# Haskell type substitution

Tags: haskell

I am going through the Haskell Book (http://haskellbook.com/) and got stuck at the following exercise:

```
f :: Float
f = 1.0

-- Question: Can you replace `f`'s signature by `f :: Num a => a`
```

At first, I thought the answer would be Yes. Float provides an instance for Num, so substituting a `Num a => a` by a `Float` value should be fine (I am thinking co-variance here).

This does not compile however:

```
Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   f :: forall a. Num a => a
        at ...
      Possible fix:
        add (Fractional a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            f :: forall a. Num a => a
    • In the expression: 1.0
      In an equation for ‘f’: f = 1.0
```

If I do this however, no problem:

```
f :: Fractional a => a
f = 1.0
```

Why can't I use a less specific constraint here like `Num a => a`?

**UPD**:

Actually, you can sum this up to:

```
1.0::(Num a => a)
```

vs

```
1.0::(Fractional a => a)
```

Why is the second working but not the first one? I thought `Fractional` was a subset of `Num` (meaning `Fractional` is compatible with `Num`)

**UPD 2:**

Thanks for your comments, but I am still confused. Why this works:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f a = a

f 1.0
```

while this not:

```
f :: Num a => a
f = 1.0
```

**UPD 3:**
I have just noticed something:

```
f :: Num a => a
f = (1::Int)
```

does not work either.

**UPD 4**

I have been reading all the answers/comments and as far as I understand:

```
f :: Num a => a
```

is the Scala equivalent of

```
def f[A: Num]: A
```

which would explain why many mentioned that `a` is defined by the caller. The only reason why we can write this:

```
f :: Num a => a 
f = 1
```

is because 1 is typed as a `Num a => a`. Could someone please confirm this assumption? In any case, thank you all for your help.

Comment: Update 3 fails because it doesn't let me write, for example, `(3.3 + f) :: Float` to get `4.3`; Haskell will not silently convert an `Int` to a `Float`. When you give something an explicit type like `Num a => a`, you give up control over what types `f` can be used as; you've already promised it can be used as *any* type that has a `Num` instance, and the *integer* 1 does not fill that roll.

Comment: In Update 2, `f :: Num a => a -> a` uses type inference to see that its argument type is `Fractional a => a`, (*not* `Float`), which means the return type is also `Fractional a => a`. All it does is return the value it is given. `f :: Num a => a`, you aren't defining a *function*; you're just defining a value, and you have already said that `f` can provide a value of *any* type that implements `Num`, which includes `Int`, but `1.0` *cannot* provide an `Int`. It's type is `Fractional a => a`, and `Int` does not have a `Fractional` instance.

Comment: @chepner: This is what confuses me. An instance of `Num` is available for Floats and `Double`. There is also an instance of `Fractional` for both of these types. So shouldn't I be able to use a `Double` or a `Float` whenever a `Num` or a `Fractional` is expected? Maybe my problem is that I think in terms of Scala implicits

Comment: `f :: Num a => a` does not mean a type with a `Num` instance is *expected*; it means *any* value whose type has a `Num` instance can be *produced*. `f = 1 :: Int` is too restrictive; `f = 1` is fine, because the literal `1` itself has type `Num a => a`. As long as a value `x` belongs to a type with a `Num` instance, I can write `x + 1`, because the `1` itself can be specialized to a matching type. The type signature does *not* mean you can assign any *monomorphic* value that happens to have a `Num` instance to `f`, the value itself needs to be just as polymorphic.

Comment: When it comes to assignment, read `g :: Num a => a` to mean "`g` holds values of *every* type except those without `Num` instances" instead of "`g` holds a value of some type that has a `Num` instance". See the difference?

Answer (score 8):

If I have `f :: Num a => a` this means that I can use `f` wherever I need any numeric type. So, all of `f :: Int`, `f :: Double` must type check.

In your case, we can't have `1.0 :: Int` for the same reason we can't have `543.24 :: Int`, that is, `Int` does not represent fractional values. However, `1.0` does fit any fractional type (as `543.24` does).

`Fractional` indeed can be thought as a subset of `Num`. But if I have a value inside *all* the fractionals `f :: forall a . Fractional a => a`, I don't necessarily have a value in all the numeric types `f :: forall a . Num a => a`.

Note that, in a sense, the constraints are on the left side of `=>`, which makes them behave *contra-variantly*. I.e. cars are a subset of vehichles, but I can't conclude that a wheel that can be used in any car will be able to be used with any vehicle. Rather, the opposite: a wheel that can be used in any vehicle will be able to be used with any car.

So, you can roughly regard `f :: forall a . Num a => a` (values fitting in any numeric type, like `3` and `5`) as a subtype of  `f :: forall a . Fractional a => a` (values fitting in any fractional type, like `3`,`5`, and `32.43`).

Comment: Isn't `Float` a `Num` type?

Comment: `Float` implements `Num`, but `1.0 :: Fractional a => a` is not a valid value for *all* types that implement `Num`.

Comment: @FrancisToth `f :: Num a => a` means that `f` can be used as a value of *any* numeric type, not that it has a single specific type which happens to be numeric.

Comment: @FrancisToth I believe the problem you are having is that you are thinking of `Num` and `Fractional` like OOP classes. If that were the case then a `Float` implementing the `Fractional` interface, also implements `Num` and you are good to go. But Typeclasses are about *parametric polymorphisms*. So `Num a => a` means "this is a polymorphic value that can have **any** type that belongs (aka has an instance) for the `Num` typeclass. But `5.12` is not a valid `Int` and `Int` is a `Num` hence `5.12` is not a valid `Num a => a`. `5.12` however belongs to the `Fractional` subset of `Num`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: In `Num a => a`, `a` can have any type that belongs to the `Num` typeclass. This includes Int among others. `Float` provides an instance for `Num`, so why a Float would not be a valid `Num`?

Comment: @FrancisToth - as others have tried (and evidently failed) to explain, you're thinking about it backwards. `a` can indeed "have any type that belongs to the `Num` typeclass`, if it has type `Num a => a`. That *any* is meant literally, and it's a pretty strong condition. In particular, `Int` belongs to the `Num` typeclass, so anything with that type signature *must* be able to have type `Int`. (Amongst many others.) But `1.0` *cannot* have type `Int`, because it can have any type that is an instance of `Fractional` - and `Int` isn't such an instance.

Comment: But don't feel bad if this is hard to take in. I recall getting confused by similar things recently in trying to learn some slightly more advanced Haskell topics (the fact that certain types with a `Functor` constraint in their type are actually more restrictive than the same types with an `Applicative` constraint).

Comment: @FrancisToth You should really try to understand the example chi provided where they put the explicit quantifier. The actual type is `f :: forall a. Num a => a`. So `f` is a value whose type is `a` ***FORALL*** possible types `a` that belong to `Num`. if `f = 5.12` then being a non integer value obviously `f` cannot be an `Int` or `Integer`, hence the forall fails. You are thinking about the type with the *exists* quantifier, which is a different type.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the *monomorphic* case:

```
f :: Float
f = 1.0
```

Here, you've said that `f` is a `Float`; not an `Int`, not a `Double`, not any other type. `1.0`, on the other hand, is a *polymorphic* constant; it has type `Fractional a => a`, and so can be used to provide a value of *any* type that has a `Fractional` instance. You can restrict it to `Float`, or `Double`, etc. Since `f` has to be a `Float`, that's what `1.0` is restricted to.

If you try to change the signature

```
f :: Num a => a
f = 1.0
```

now you have a problem. You've now promised that `f` can be used to *provide* a value of *any* type that has a `Num` instance. That includes `Int` and `Integer`, but neither of those types has a `Fractional` instance. So, the compiler refuses to let you do this. `1.0` simply can't produce an `Int` should the need arise.

Likewise,

```
1.0::(Num a => a)
```

is a lie, because this isn't a restriction; it's an attempt at *expanding* the set of types that `1.0` can produce. Something with type `Num a => a` should be able to give me an `Int`, but `1.0` cannot do that.

```
1.0::(Fractional a => a)
```

works because you are just restating something that is already true. It's neither restricting `1.0` to a smaller set of types or trying to expand it.

---

Now we get something a little more interesting, because you are specifying a *function* type, not just a value type.

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f a = a
```

This just says that `f` can take as its argument any value that is *no more polymorphic* than `Num a => a`. `a` can be any type that implements `Num`, or it can be a polymorphic value that is a *subset* of the types that represent `Num`.
You chose

```
f 1.0
```

which means `a` gets unified with `Fractional a => a`. Type inference then decides that the return type is also `Fractional a => a`, and returning the same value you passed in is allowed.

---

We've already covered why this

```
f :: Num a => a
f = 1.0
```

isn't allowed above, and

```
f :: Num a => a
f = (1::Int)
```

fails for the same reason. `Int` is simply too specific; it is *not* the same as `Num a => a`.

For example, `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` requires two arguments of the same type. So, I might try to write

```
1 :: Integer + f
```

*or*

```
1 :: Float + f
```

. In both cases, I need `f` to be able to provide a value with the same type as the other argument, to satisfy the type of `(+)`: if I want an `Integer`, I should be able to get an `Integer`, and if I want a `Float`, I should be able to get a `Float`. But if you could specify a value with something less specific than `Num a => a`, you wouldn't be able to keep that promise. `1.0 :: Fractional a => a` can't provide an `Integer`, and `1 :: Int` can't provide  *anything* except an `Int`, not even an `Integer`.

---

Think of a polymorphic type as a function from a concrete type to a value; you can literally do this if you enable the `TypeApplications` extension.

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications
Prelude> :{
Prelude| f :: Num a => a
Prelude| f = 1
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => a
Prelude> :t f @Int
f @Int :: Int
Prelude> f @Int
1
Prelude> :t f @Float
f @Float :: Float
Prelude> f @Float
1.0
Prelude> :t f @Rational
f @Rational :: Rational
Prelude> f @Rational
1 % 1
```

The reason these all work is because you promised that you could pass *any* type with a `Num` instance to `f`, and it could return a value of that type. But if you had been allowed to say `f = 1.0`, there is *no way* that `f @Int` could, in fact, return an `Int`, because `1.0` simply *is not capable* of producing an `Int`.

Comment: I feel really dumb and am really sorry about that. You said that: `You've now promised that f can be used to provide a value of any type that has a Num instance. That includes Int and Integer`- but also `Double` and `Float` as shown by `:i Num` (hence my confusion). You also said: `but neither of those types has a Fractional instance.` - why does that matter? Covariance is maybe what messes me up. I think about `Double` as a type holding both the Num and the Fractional contract. So it has the capabilities to be used wherever one or the other is expected.

Comment: @FrancisToth - the key word in that sentence you quoted is "any". Yes, `Double` and `Float` have `Num` instances, and they are possible types of `1.0`. But the type signature `Num a => a` promises that its value can be used with any instance of `Num`. `Int` and `Integer` are included in that "any", and are not possible types for `1.0` - and that's why this does't work. It's rather like using `2` to prove that not all prime numbers are odd - the fact that many other primes, indeed all other primes, are odd is irrelevant.

Comment: @FrancisToth I think you keep assuming that Haskell supports [subtype polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping); it does not. Typeclasses are not classes in the sense of object-oriented programming, where any instance of a subclass is-a instance of a superclass. Rather, it is a *requirement* that an instance of a superclass exist before you can define a *separate* instance for a subclass. (I.e., `Real` has both `Num` and `Ord` as superclasses. That doesn't mean defining a `Real` instance for a type automatically gives it both `Num` and `Ord` instances...

Comment: ... Quite the opposite, it means you *cannot* define a `Real` instance unless you have *already* defined both `Num` and `Ord` instances for the type.

Answer (score 2):

When values with polymorphic types like `Num a => a` are involved, there are two sides. The **source** of the value, and the **use** of the value. One side gets the flexibility to choose any specific type compatible with the polymorphic type (like using `Float` for `Num a => a`). The other side is restricted to using code that will work *regardless* of which specific type is involved - it can *only* make use of features that will work for **every** type compatible with the polymorphic type.

There is no free lunch; both sides cannot have the same freedom to pick any compatible type they like.

This is just as true for object-oriented subclass polymorphism, however OO polymorphism rules give the flexibility to the **source** side, and put all the restrictions on the **use** side (except for generics, which works like parametric polymorphism), while Haskell's parametric polymorphism gives the flexibility to the use side, and puts all the restrictions on the source side.

For example in an OO language with a general number class `Num`, and `Int` and `Double` as subclasses of this, then a method returning something of type `Num` would work the way you're expecting. You can return `1.0 :: Double`, but the caller can't use any methods on the value that are provided specifically by `Double` (like say one that splits off the fractional part) because the caller must be programmed to work the same whether you return an `Int` or a `Double` (or even any brand new subclass of `Num` that is private to your code, that the caller cannot possibly know about).

Polymorphism in Haskell is based on type parameters rather than subtyping, which switches things around. The place in the code where `f :: Num a => a` is used has the freedom to demand any particular choice for `a` (subject to the `Num` constraint), and the code for `f` that is the source of the value must be programmed to work *regardless* of the use-site's choice. The use-site is even free to demand values of a type that is private to the code using `f`, that the implementer of `f` cannot possibly know about. (I can literally open up a new file, make any bizarre new type I like and give it an instance for `Num`, and any of the standard library functions written years ago that are polymorphic in `Num` will work with my type)

So this works:

```
f :: Float
f = 1.0
```

Because there are no type variables, so both source and use-site simply have to treat this as a `Float`. But this does not:

```
f :: Num a => a
f = 1.0
```

Because the place where `f` is *used* can demand *any* valid choice for `a`, and this code must be able to work for that choice. (It would not work when `Int` is chosen, for example, so the compiler must reject this definition of `f`). But this does work:

```
f :: Fractional a => a
f = 1.0
```

Because now the use site is only free to demand any type that is in `Fractional`, which excludes the ones (like `Int`) that floating point literals like `1.0` cannot support.

Note that this is *exactly* how "generics" work in object oriented languages, so if you're familiar with any language supporting generics, just treat Haskell types the way you do generic ones in OO languages.

---

One further thing that may be confusing you is that in this:

```
f :: Float
f = 1.0
```

The literal `1.0` isn't actually definitively a `Float`. Haskell literals are much more flexible than those of most other languages. Whereas e.g. Java says that `1.0` is definitely a value of type `double` (with some automatic conversion rules if you use a `double` where certain other types are expected), in Haskell that `1.0` is actually itself a thing with a polymorphic type. `1.0` has type `Fractional a => a`.

So the reason the `f :: Fractional a => a` definition worked is obvious, it's actually the `f :: Float` definition that needs some explanation. It's making use of exactly the rules I described above in the first section of my post. Your code `f = 1.0` is a **use-site** of the value represented by `1.0`, so it can demand any type it likes (subject to `Fractional`). In particular, it can demand that the literal `1.0` supply a value of type `Float`.

This again reinforces why the `f :: Num a => a` definition can't work. Here the type for `f` is promising to `f`'s callers that they can demand any type they like (subject to `Num`). But it's going to fulfill that demand by just passing the demand down the chain to the literal `1.0`, which has the most general type of `Fractional a => a`. So if the use-site of `f` demands a type that is in `Num` but outside `Fractional`, `f` would then try to demand that `1.0` supply that same non-`Fractional` type, which it can't.

Comment: I looked at all answers/comment and feel that I am starting to get it. The key here is to understand that type parameters are decided (like in `a`) by the caller. If I assign `f` to à an argument that expects an Int, I need to make sure that the `a` being returned is an Int. Not a `Double`. In the same way, if I expect a Float, `f` cannot return a Double either. So `Num a => a` cannot return an Int, nor a Float or a Double. It can only return a `Num a => a` which happens to be the type of `1` for example. If this is correct, I will update my question and provide a better explanation.

Comment: When you think about it, this the equivalent of `def f[T: Num]: T = ???` in Scala

Answer (score 1):

Names do not have types. Values have types, and the type is an intrinsic part of the value. `1 :: Int` and `1 :: Integer` are two different values. Haskell does not implicitly convert values between types, though it can be trivial to define functions that take values of one type and return values of another. (For example, `f :: Int -> Integer` with `f x = x` will "convert" its `Int` arugment to an `Integer`.

A declaration like

```
f :: Num a => a
```

does not say that `f` has type `Num a => a`, it says that you can assign values of type `Num a => a` to `f`.

You can think of a polymorphic value like `1 :: Num a => a` being all `1`-like values in every type with a `Num` instance, including `1 :: Int`, `1 :: Integer`, `1 :: Rational`, etc.

An assignment like `f = 1` succeeds because the literal `1` has the expected type `Num a => a`.

An assignment like `f = 1.0` fails because the literal `1.0` has a different type, `Fractional a => a`, and that type is too specific. It does not include all `1`-like values that `Num a => a` may be called on to produce.

Suppose you declared `g :: Fractional a => a`. You can say `g = 1.0`, because the types match. You cannot say `g = (1.0 :: Float)`, because the types do not match; `Float` has a `Fractional` instance, but it is just one of a possibly infinite set of types that could have `Fractional` instances.

You *can* say `g = 1`, because `Fractional a => a` is *more* specific than `Num a => a`, and has `Fractional` has `Num` as its superclass. The assignment "selects" the subset of `1 :: Num a => a` that overlaps with (and for all intents and purposes *is*) `1 :: Fractional a => a` and assigns that to `g`. Put another way, just `1 :: Num a => a` can produce a value for any *single* type that has a `Num` instance, it can produce a value for any *subset* of types implied by a subclass of `Num`.

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled by this as well.

What gets stuck in my mind is something like:

```js
// in pseudo-typescript

type Num = Int | Float;

let f: Num;
f = (1.0 as Float); // why this doesn't work
```

Fact is, `Num a => a` is just not a simple sum of numeric types.
It represents **something that can morph into various kind of numeric types**.

Thanks to chepner's explanation, now I can persuade myself like this:

if I have a `Num a => a` then I can get a `Int` from it,  I can also get a `Float` from it, as well as a `Double`....

If I am able to install `1.1` into a `Num a => a`, then there is no way I can safely derive a `Int` from `1.1`.

The expression `1` is able to bind to `Num a => a` is due to the fact that `1` itself is a *polymorphic constant* with type signature `Num a => a`.